Add outputs to argo workflow templateRef
I need to set the output for a templateRef.
My template hierarchy is build like this:

DefaultTemplate
SpecificTemplate using DefaultTemplate
Workflow using one or many SpecificTemplates

The SpecificTemplate can have different outputs than the DefaultTemplate as it executes different code.
Is there a way to set outputs for these specific templates?
Example SpecificTemplate:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterWorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: wft-if-else
spec:
  templates:
  - name: run-specific-wft
    steps:
    - - name: step-first
        template: task-test
        when: "{{workflow.parameters.test_param}} == 'test'"
    - - name: step-if-one
        template: task-test
        when: "{{steps.step-first.outputs.parameters.result}} == '1'"
    - - name: step-if-zero
        template: task-test
        when: "{{steps.step-first.outputs.parameters.result}} == '0'"

  - name: task-test
    templateRef:
      name: default-template   # <- This is the DefaultTemplate
      template: run-default
      clusterScope: true 
    arguments:
      parameters:
      - name: image
        value: $TASK_IMAGE:$IMAGE_VER
    outputs:
      parameters:
      - name: result
        valueFrom:
          path: /tmp/test.txt

This leads to the error: json: unknown field "outputs"
